# Is this sentence wrong if I change "the" to "my"?

Tags: grammar

> 1. This is **the** first time that I've tasted soy sauce
> 2. This is **my** first time that I've tasted soy sauce

Some people say it's correct to write "the", not "my" and they correct 2 as "This is my first time tasting soy sauce"

Is there any reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *my* instead of *the*.

However, the second example sentence is ungrammatical. You can't just replace *the* with *my*; you need to make some other changes (as you've mentioned).

Both of these are fine:

> 1. This is **the** first time that I've tasted soy sauce.
> 2. This is **my** first time **tasting** soy sauce.

They mean essentially the same thing.

---

The original second sentence is wrong because *that I've tasted soy cause* can't follow as an object of *my* (or *my first time*).

> ✘ My *that red car*.
>   ✔ My *red car*.
>
> ✘ My *that running ritual*.
>   ✔ My *running ritual*.

---

An alternative phrasing that uses *my* would be:

> 2. b) This is **my** first **taste of** soy sauce.

Answer (score 2):

Whose other first time might you be speaking of? "My" is redundant since it's *your* first taste.

Comment: Is this because it's redundant to repeat "I" because "my" already makes it clear that whose time it's referring to?

I think this seems to be the main reason making sentence 2 sound awkward.

Comment: That's correct.